# Why a new project templates in Android Studio 3.2.1 does not use the AndroidX libraries?

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

Google says

> "We recommend using the AndroidX libraries in all new projects. You
>   should also consider migrating existing projects to AndroidX as well."
>   [source](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/)

but the Android Studio 3.2.1 still creates a new project templates which are supported by the historical "android.support.*" libraries.

Why?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.developer.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not until [Android Studio 3.3](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/) or higher (currently still *Preview/Beta*).

If you create a new project with it, you'll find this `Use AndroidX artifacts` option. Then once created, you'll find that the dependencies are defaulted with `androidx.*`

[image]